# Move file after Streaming Pipeline dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, streaming, google-cloud-dataflow

I created a streaming apache beam pipeline that read files from GCS folders and insert them in bigtable, it works perfectly but I would like to moves the proccessed files in a new GCS folder(OK folder) to indicate that these files have been proccessed by the pipeline.
Is there a technical solution to do that with apache beam ?

```
    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

    CloudBigtableTableConfiguration bigtableTableConfig =
            new CloudBigtableTableConfiguration.Builder()
                    .withProjectId(options.getProjectId())
                    .withInstanceId(options.getBigtableInstanceId())
                    .withAppProfileId("default")
                    .withTableId(options.getBigtableTableId())
                    .build();

    // pipeline
    p.apply("read from csv", TextIO.read().from(options.getInputFilePattern()).watchForNewFiles(DEFAULT_POLL_INTERVAL, Growth.never()))
            .apply("Transfrom to Bigtable", ParDo.of(new TextToBigtableFn(options.getBigtableInstanceId(), options.getBigtableTableId())))
            .apply("write into bigtable", CloudBigtableIO.writeToTable(bigtableTableConfig));

    p.run();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately applying a CloudBigtableIO does not return a meaningful result (it's a `PDone`) that can be followed, though this is something [we'd like to change](https://lists.apache.org/thread/vzrq7zx28dl79k41psvy247p6fb99tgd).